# Ubuntu: how to check when system clock was adjusted

Tags: ubuntu, ntp, ntpd

I'm trying to figure out when the `ntpd` adjusted the system clock on Ubuntu 17.10. The `ntpq -pn` utility shows when the client synchronized with the server last. But it doesn't show when it desided to update the local system clock.

Is there a way to see this event?

Thank you.